# Command needed to mount a LUKS partition on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, luks, cryptsetup

Ubuntu  -

I need to mount my LUKS encrypted partitions in **read only** mode.

Have searched online, but no commands have worked.

```
$ lsblk
SDA 8:0 0 5.5T 0 disk
SDA1 8:1 0 1.4T 0 part
Partition name 253:0 1.4T 0 crypt
SDA2(3,4) 8:2 0 1.4T 0 part
```

**UPDATE**:
I am able to open each luks partition using:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 partn.name
```

**QUESTION**: what luks command will mount the partition(s) using read only?

Comment: This Question belongs on AskUbuntu, where it's a dup of https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line

Comment: That link doessn't seem to say anything about mounting in "read-only", does it? Thx

Comment: There `-r` and `-o ro`, in case you haven't checked the man page of `mount`. Besides, no one can tell what exactly you mean by `no commands have worked`.

Comment: Command: sudo mount -o ro /dev/mapper/partn.name /mnt